# python django how can i filter object_set.all by current user in template

Tags: python, django

http://pastebin.com/Aa5rJxv8

i have django problem above, i tried to explain
i need to show ratings given by current user to books in user shelves

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this in the template would be to define a [custom filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters). This custom filter can accept a queryset and the currently logged in user as arguments and do the necessary filtering.

```
@register.filter
def filter_by_user(queryset, user):
    """Filter the queryset by (currently logged in) user"""
    return queryset.filter(added_by = user)
```

And in the template:

```
<td>{{ book.rating_set.all|filter_by_user:user|safeseq|join:", " }}</td>
```